# The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed

Tags: wcf

This is a bit different than other questions I've found on SO regarding this issue...

We're running 2 websites, one a WCF service and the other is a client to the service. Whenever we try to access the service we get the message "The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed."

**Both the websites are hosted on the same machine and under the same App Pool.** Both websites are hosted on port 80 and have different host headers... example: client.website.com and service.website.com

We're using wsHttpBinding on the service side:

```
        <endpoint address="http://service.website.com/MessagingService.svc/wshttp"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="WebServices.IMessagingService"
            bindingNamespace="CNI/CNIMessenger"
            bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig"
            name="wsHttpBinding">
        </endpoint>
```

When we try to run the service we get the above mentioned error. After hours of debugging I was able to find that if I use a service configuration address without any url only **wshttp** and point my client to the IP Address/Port everything works fine. for example:

```
<endpoint address="wshttp"
... And client address points to: http://127.0.0.1:8888/MessagingService.svc/wshttp
```

When I change the address and website to use service.website.com and keep the port 8888 I continue to get the same error.

Does anyone have any insight on this? MANY Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your configuration:

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://service.website.com"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

keep the address as wshttp